# ScalaJs + ZIO: Program works with sbt 1.2.8 but not >= 1.3

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js, zio

I'm trying out scala.js with zio using the sample app at
https://github.com/wongelz/zio-scalajs-solarsystem

as soon as I update the sbt version from 1.2.8 to 1.3.13 or 1.4.4 I'm getting the following error:

```
[error] Referring to non-existent method java.time.LocalTime$.NANOS_PER_SECOND()long
[error]   called from private java.time.LocalDateTime.plusWithOverflow(java.time.LocalDate,long,long,long,long,int)java.time.LocalDateTime
[error]   called from java.time.LocalDateTime.plusNanos(long)java.time.LocalDateTime
[error]   called from java.time.LocalDateTime.plus(long,java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)java.time.LocalDateTime
[error]   called from java.time.LocalDateTime.plus(long,java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)java.time.temporal.Temporal
[error]   called from java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.addTo(java.time.temporal.Temporal,long)java.time.temporal.Temporal
[error]   called from java.time.OffsetDateTime.plus(long,java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)java.time.OffsetDateTime
[error]   called from java.time.OffsetDateTime.plus(long,java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)java.time.temporal.Temporal
[error]   called from java.time.Duration.addTo(java.time.temporal.Temporal)java.time.temporal.Temporal
[error]   called from java.time.OffsetDateTime.plus(java.time.temporal.TemporalAmount)java.time.OffsetDateTime
[error]   called from private zio.Schedule$.$anonfun$fixed$2(scala.Option,java.time.OffsetDateTime,long,java.time.Duration,long,scala.runtime.LazyRef)zio.Schedule$Decision
[error]   called from private zio.Schedule$.$anonfun$fixed$1(scala.Option,long,java.time.Duration,long,scala.runtime.LazyRef,java.time.OffsetDateTime,java.lang.Object)zio.ZIO
[error]   called from private zio.Schedule$.loop$23(scala.Option,long,long,java.time.Duration,scala.runtime.LazyRef)scala.Function2
[error]   called from zio.Schedule$.fixed(java.time.Duration)zio.Schedule
[error]   called from private SolarSystemExample$.$anonfun$run$1(SolarSystemExample$SolarSystem)zio.ZIO
[error]   called from SolarSystemExample$.run(scala.collection.immutable.List)zio.ZIO
[error]   called from private zio.App.$anonfun$main$1([java.lang.String)zio.ZIO
[error]   called from zio.App.main([java.lang.String)void
[error]   called from SolarSystemExample$.main([java.lang.String)void
[error]   called from static SolarSystemExample.main([java.lang.String)void
[error]   called from core module module initializers
[error] involving instantiated classes:
[error]   java.time.LocalDateTime
[error]   java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit
[error]   java.time.OffsetDateTime
[error]   java.time.Duration
[error]   zio.Schedule$
[error]   SolarSystemExample$
```

Why does this bug happen? And where should I report it?

Comment: Does `show compile:fullClasspath` report different results in any 1.3+ versus 1.2, perhaps?

Comment: the classpaths uses the same libraries. However, I figured out that the project includes `scalajs-java-time_sjs1_2.13-1.0.0.jar` as well as `scala-java-time_sjs1_2.13-2.0.0.jar`. The `scalajs-java-time` is marked as deprecated and incomplete on github. sbt 1.2.8 places it last in the classpath, while sbt 1.3.13 places it before the 'scala-java-time' library. So I think it is picked first in sbt >1.3 and because its less complete than the 'scala-java-time' library the compiler throws an error. So classpath ordering changed between 1.2.8 and 1.3.x. I removed the scalajs-java-time and it compiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question (for anybody strugling with the same problem):

**Make sure you don't have `scalajs-java-time` (1.0.0) as a dependency in your classpath.**
It is a incomplete library and if it is picked before `scala-java-time` you will receive the error posted in the question.

The reason this error occurred, was, that at least on my system, the ordering of the classpath changed from **sbt 1.2.8** to **sbt 1.3.x**, which resulted in the `scalajs-java-time` library being picked before `scala-java-time` which resulted in the

```
Referring to non-existent method java.time.LocalTime$.NANOS_PER_SECOND()long
```

Error